# Angular2 definition file errors

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm getting the following errors when compiling an application against AngularJS 2.0 RC1 using the TypeScript 1.8.10 compiler.

```
ERROR in [default] [...]/www/node_modules/@angular/testing/src/mock/mock_application_ref.d.ts:6:
Generic type 'ComponentRef<C>' requires 1 type argument(s).

ERROR in [default] [...]/www/node_modules/@angular/testing/src/mock/mock_application_ref.d.ts:8:
Generic type 'ComponentFactory<C>' requires 1 type argument(s).

ERROR in [default] [...]/www/node_modules/@angular/testing/src/mock/mock_application_ref.d.ts:8:
Generic type 'ComponentRef<C>' requires 1 type argument(s).

ERROR in [default] [...]/www/node_modules/@angular/testing/src/mock/schema_registry_mock.d.ts:2:
Class 'MockSchemaRegistry' incorrectly implements interface 'ElementSchemaRegistry'.
  Property 'securityContext' is missing in type 'MockSchemaRegistry'.

ERROR in [default] [...]/www/node_modules/@angular/testing/src/test_component_builder.d.ts:26:18
Generic type 'ComponentRef<C>' requires 1 type argument(s).

ERROR in [default] [...]/www/node_modules/@angular/testing/src/test_component_builder.d.ts:31:30
Generic type 'ComponentRef<C>' requires 1 type argument(s).
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change all the imports `from '@angular/testing';` to `from '@angular/core/testing';`

This worked for me ;)